# data-bind text inside another foreach loop knockout

Tags: data-binding, foreach, knockout.js

bind text of same model inside a foreach loop but that text is not a part of that array.

```
function SmsViewModel(data,id) {
    var self = this;

    // Editable data
    self.Sms = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(data));
    self.Num = ko.observable('Send SMS');
    self.removeNumber = function(item){
    }
    self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
 if ($(id).children().length === ko.toJS(self.Sms).length) {
        // Only now execute handler
    jq();
    }
}   


}
```

when i display data of sms it works fine but i am not able to display sel.Num in same foreach

```
<div class="modalbox_content" data-bind="foreach: {data: Sms,afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic}" id="KnockOutSmsData">

              <!-- ko if: FromAddress === '+18038004697' && TypeOfMassage === 'I' -->
                <div class="message_container" >

                  <div class="message_user_photo"><img src="images/user_pic.png" width="40" height="40"/></div>
                  <div class="message_cell_number"><span data-bind="text: FromAddress"></span></div>
                  <div class="recieved_message_container">
                    <div class="recieved_message_arrow"></div>
                    <div class="recieved_message_box">
                      <p><span data-bind="text: Body"></span></p>
                      <div class="forwd_message"><a href="#"><img src="images/frwd_msg.png"/></a></div>
                      <span data-bind="text: MsgDateTime"></span></div>

                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- close message container -->
                <!-- ko if: ToAddress === '+18038004697' && TypeOfMassage === 'S' -->
                <div class="message_container" >

                  <div class="sent_message_user_photo"><img src="images/user_pic.png" width="40" height="40"/></div>
                  <div class="sent_message_cell_number"><span data-bind="text: ToAddress"></div>
                  <div class="sent_message_container">
                    <div class="sent_message_arrow"></div>
                    <div class="sent_message_box">
                      <p><span data-bind="text: Body"></span></p>
                      <span data-bind="text: MsgDateTime"></span></div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- close message container --> 

              </div>
```

i just want to compare

```
<!-- ko if: FromAddress === self.Num && TypeOfMassage === 'I' -->
```

this self.Num is the part of

```
self.Num = ko.observable('Send SMS');
```

and FromAddress is the part of

```
  self.Sms = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(data));
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `$parent` [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) variable with that you can access the "parent" object inside a `foreach`:

```
<!-- ko if: FromAddress === $parent.Num() && TypeOfMassage === 'I' -->
```

Note that you need write `$parent.Num()` (e.g. with `()`) because `Num` is a `ko.observable`

Here is a  [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/4mn6G/2/) which is based roughly on your code.

Comment: @rohitarora can you be more specific? Are there any errors in console? Are you sure that `self.Num` contains the right value. Beucase in your sample it is not a number but a text `'Send SMS'` : `self.Num = ko.observable('Send SMS');`.

Comment: no actually i am assigning value to self.Num in a function when a click bind is occured its a number actually

self.AddNum = function(item){
 self.Num(item.FromAddress);
 }

now self.Num is a number..it is setting the value as i alert(item.FromAddress);

Comment: In theory it should work. Maybe you try with double `==` so `FromAddress == $parent.Num()`. Can you have a look this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/4mn6G/2/ it is based roughly on your code and working.

Comment: <a class="sendsms" href="#sendsms" rel="#sendsms" data-bind="click: $parent.AddNumber">

when this function works i get value in this function in item

function(item){ self.Num(item.FromAddress); }

but i am not able to set value to 

self.Num